# command line arguments in array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am a very beginner in Java, I have a question regarding to use command line arguments line in array, for example, I tried to type:

```
double []a=Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
```

however, it said" cannot convert double to double",I cannot figure out it, as I can do

```
double a=Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
```

so what is wrong with using CL arguments input in array then?Thanks

Comment: `Double.parseDouble(args[0])` returns you a single value, not an array.

Comment: You can't assign a `double` to a `double[]` array.

Comment: When you wonder what a method does, consult its javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

Comment: thanks guys, so how should I write if I wanna do command line input in an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, [`Double.parseDouble()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29) returns a `double` as opposed to a `double[]`, so you can't assign it to a variable of type `double[]`.

If you want to convert all of the strings in `args` to `double`s, you could try something like

```
double[] a = new double[args.length];
for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    a[i] = Double.parseDouble(args[i]);
}
```

Of course, if you just want `args[0]`, then store the parsed `double` as you are doing in your second snippet; not much sense in using an array in this case.

Answer (score 1):

> however, it said" cannot convert double to double",I cannot figure out it, as I can do

What it *actually* said was "cannot convert `double` to `double[]`".  The `[]` is crucial to the meaning of the error message ... and you shouldn't ignore it.

It is telling you that you cannot treat a `double` as an array of `double`.

---

If you want to initialize a `double[]`, you need to allocate a `double` array first; e.g.

```
double [] a = new double[1];
a[0] = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
```

Or you could do that in one statement:

```
double [] a = new double[]{Double.parseDouble(args[0])};
```

or even

```
double [] a = {Double.parseDouble(args[0])};
```

Answer (score 0):

It must be an array that is assigned...

e.g.

```
double[] a = new double[] { Double.parseDouble(args[0]) };
```